# Can we use SLES 11 SP4 RPM on SLES 11 SP3?

Tags: rpm

If the RPM is needed for SLES 11 SP3 is not available but the same RPM is available for SLES 11 SP4. Is it possible to use the SP4 RPM on SP3?

Is this allowed, or the RPM are dependent on the kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe*. The RPM itself won't stop you unless there's a conflict. For example, if it is compiled C code, it may require the C libraries from the newer OS and it won't work. So my answer is "try it and see" because it's not something that can be answered without more details. If it's a "`noarch`" package, you have a much better chance.